# creating a weakref to pydantic model

Tags: python, weak-references, pydantic

Is it possible to create a weakref of a pydantic model ?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID

class JEdgeModel(BaseModel):
    uid: UUID
    startSocket: UUID
    destnSocket: UUID

a = JEdgeModel(uid='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d', startSocket='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d', destnSocket='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d')

wk = weakref.ref(a)
```

I get the following error :
`cannot create weak reference to 'JEdgeModel' object`

Is there a way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Hi : could you explain a bit more of context ? Why do you need a weak reference here ?

Comment: You'd need to add the required field `__weakref__` to `BaseModel.__slots__` to make the class support weak references.

Comment: @DanD. thanks, if u answer i can mark it as a sollution

Comment: @jossefaz m creating PyQt app, i need to pass the ref of a model I need to update. I know I can update a copy of the model in a new window and send it back, but creating a weakref of the same saves me some hassle. I am not sure if its a good practice to solve the problem like this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots)

> Without a **weakref** variable for each instance, classes defining **slots** do not support weak references to its instances. If weak reference support is needed, then add '**weakref**' to the sequence of strings in the **slots** declaration.

So just add `__weakref__` to your `__slot__` in your model

```py
class JEdgeModel(BaseModel):
    __slots__ = ['__weakref__']
    uid: UUID
    startSocket: UUID
    destnSocket: UUID

a = JEdgeModel(
    uid='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d',
    startSocket='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d',
    destnSocket='abd6fc3f882544f5b75661c92fccbd0d',
)

wk = weakref.ref(a)
```